# asp.net dropdownlist in gridview

Tags: asp.net

im working on an asp.net website with a gridview.

The gridview has data from an sql database.

Like:

```
Cuntry----Name
USA--------John
England----Frank
```

...

The data is loaded in to the gridview like this:

```
SqlCommand cmd;
        cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.Connection = sqlConn;
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.CommandText = "sp_loadData";
        sqlConn.Open();

        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Load(dr);
        GridView1.DataSource = dt;
        GridView1.DataBind();
```

So, in the name column, i want a dropdownlist. And I want the dropdownlist with the corresponding value from the database selected.

How can I do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" 
  OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound">    
  <Columns>
  <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Country">
    <ItemTemplate>
      <asp:DropDownList Width="50" runat="server" id="ddlCountry" AutoPostBack="true">
      </asp:DropDownList> 
    </ItemTemplate>
  </asp:TemplateField>
</asp:GridView>
```

**In Code-behind**

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    //Checking whether the Row is Data Row
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        //Finding the Dropdown control.
        Control ctrl = e.Row.FindControl("ddlCountry");
        if (ctrl != null)
        {
            DropDownList dd = ctrl as DropDownList;
            //Here Bind with country list
            dd.DataSource = lst;
            //Put here the object properties name
            dd.DataValueField = "idCountry";
            dd.DataTextField = "nameCountry";
            dd.DataBind();
            //Here add the code to select the current user country in the list
            int idUserCountry = 10;
            dd.Items.FindByValue(idUserCountry).Selected = true;

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: im doing this:

 `code
    cmd = new SqlCommand();
                cmd.Connection = sqlConn;
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.CommandText = "sp_Select";
                sqlConn.Open();
                dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                dt.Load(dr);
                dd.DataSource = dt;
                dd.DataBind();
`
....
but when i execute, in the dropdownlist, all i get is: "System.Data.DataRowView". No actual values are shown.
How can I fix this?

Comment: inside the protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)

Comment: this part is not working: `code    //Here add the code to select the current user country in the list
            int idUserCountry = 10;
            dd.Items.FindByValue(idUserCountry).Selected = true;
`.............it gives me a nullreference exception..........what can I do?

Comment: This is only an example if you have null reference exception it means you dont have a country with id=10. 
I Cant give you the whole code, you have to adapt to your problem, you got here 99% of the job done, so make the last effort, for example you can use the debug mode to find out. Come on, understanding and copy pasting is not the same thing :)

Comment: You are right. I did the effort. Its working good now. Thanks for all the help!